# Layer7 DDoS Protection vs WAF, which should I use?

Tags: attacks, attack-prevention, ddos, waf

I have Layer3 ddos protection, but I want to upgrade it to Layer7 ddos protection. But when i look about Layer7 Ddos attacks, I see that they are usually HTTP/HTTPS based attacks. I have 3 questions;

1. What is other Layer7 DDos attacks, e.g FTP, DNS ?
2. If I use WAF instead of Layer7 ddos protection, what will be risks in my system?
3. Using WAF for ddos protection is a prefered way?

Comment: Can you clarify that the application you're protecting is a HTTP web-service?

Comment: I protected HTTP/s web service via WAF. But is it enough? what about my ftp, dns servers?

Comment: You can use WAF and DDoS protection in parallel (they're not mutually exclusive). In fact, WAF-only will likely not protect you against a *Distributed Denial of Service* (DDoS) attack. WAF will scrutinise the actual protocol requests that would be sent to the HTTP service.

Comment: DDoS protection may also protect your FTP service, while a *Web Application Firewall* (WAF) probably won't.

Comment: You probably need to add more information, what is your architecture ? A classic web server in DMZ and the rest behind a firewall ? are you trying to protect from ? External DDOS or also internal ? If you use both WAF and DDos protection, you want to put the DDOS protection in front of the WAF.

Comment: I will buy Layer7 ddos protection against applicaton-level attacks. But i think WAF also blocks lots of attacks which come to web server. I have generally web server at DMZ, but also there are servers for dns, ftp, ntp etc. I will buy external DDOS Protection, from ISP. My question is what WAF can NOT protect? What is advantage of having ISP DDOS Protection comparing to internal WAF?

Comment: *"I have **two** questions : 1. ... 2. ... __3__. ..."* - hm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.What is other Layer7 DDos attacks, e.g FTP, DNS ?**

> Application layer attacks or layer 7 (L7) DDoS attacks refer to a type
> of malicious behavior designed to target the “top” layer in the OSI
> model where common internet requests such as HTTP GET and HTTP POST
> occur. These layer 7 attacks, in contrast to network layer attacks
> such as DNS Amplification, are particularly effective due to their
> consumption of server resources in addition to network resources.

**2.If I use WAF instead of Layer7 ddos protection, what will be risks in my system?**

WAF can mitigate ddos attack in under certain level. Application layer ddos attacks are very difficult to avoid. Specially bot net attacks are not spoofed and request seems to be fully legitimate.

**3.Using WAF for ddos protection is a prefered way?**

You have to use adaptive technology like a captcha code. Because botnet attacks are very difficult to identified from legitimate traffic therefore captcha will be best solution.

Web application Firewall also option. Please Read [link](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ddos/application-layer-ddos-attack/).

*(Details copied from cloudflare)*